# Problem of three circles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

This geometrical problem was proposed in a Mathematics Contest for high school students of my country. It is truly hard to find its solution.

---

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle inscribed in the circle with its center $O$. The line which is perpendicular to $AO$ at $O$ intersects $AB$ and $AC$ at $E$ and $F$ respectively.

Let $D$ be the intersection point of $BF$ and $CE$. The circumscribed circle of triangle $BDC$ intersects $AB$ and $AC$ at $M$ and $N$ respectively and the circumscribed circle of triangle $DEF$ intersects $AB$ and $AC$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

Let $S$ be the intersection point of $BC$ and $EF$, and $K$ be the intersection point of $PN$ and $MQ$.

> Prove that $AK\perp SD$.

**I am happy if someone could propose some fresh ideas to attack this problem.**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(WXYZ)$ denote the circumcircle of any cyclic quadrilateral $WXYZ$.

$EFCB$ is cyclic as $\angle OEA=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle BAO=\angle ACB.$ Therefore, $PQ\|BC $ and $EF\|MN$. Also, it follows that $MNPQ$ is cyclic.

Now, $\angle DBM=\angle DCN$ as $EFCB$ is cyclic. Therefore, $DM=DN$. Similarly, $\angle DEP=\angle DFQ$ as $EFCB$ is cyclic. Consequently, $DP=DQ$. Hence, $D$ is the centre of $(MNPQ)$.

Let $MN$ intersect $PQ$ at $T$. By construction, $S$ is the [*radical center*](http://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/ebooks/pdf/EGMO_chapter2.pdf) of $(PQEF), (MNCB)$ and $(EFCB)$. So,  $SD$ is the [*radical axis*](http://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/ebooks/pdf/EGMO_chapter2.pdf) of $(PQEF)$ and $(MNCB)$. By construction, $T$ is the *radical center* of $(PQEF), (MNCB)$ and $(MNPQ)$. So, $TD$ is the *radical axis* of $(PQEF)$ and $(MNCB)$, whence, $S,\ T, D$ are collinear. Thus, $AK\perp SD \iff AK \perp TD.$

Applying [*Brokard's theorem*](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=334&lmm=0) on $MNPQ$, we have, $AK \perp TD$, as $D$ is the centre of $(MNPQ)$ and $A, K$ and $T$ are the three diagonal points of the [complete quadrangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_quadrangle) $MNPQ$.

$\blacksquare$

*Note that for any $E,\ F$ on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively such that $AEF\sim ACB$, the problem statement is true. The circumcentre of $ABC$ is irrelevant.*

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you introduce me the references for this problem?  I am grateful to you if you could explain why you could solve the problem.

Comment: Which contest did this problem appear in?

Comment: Read about radical axes at https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/ebooks/pdf/EGMO_chapter2.pdf if you are not familiar with them. Read about Brokard's theorem from the link in the answer.

Comment: As for why I could solve the problem, I have trained in olympiad geometry. If you want to know my thoughts while solving the problem, they are as follows. First, I noticed that EFCB is cyclic. Next the radical axis SD occured automatically. With a diagram on geogebra, I noticed that D is the centre of MNPQ. proving that was not too difficult. Now the problem concerned entirely of the complete quadrangle MNPQ except for the line SD. I linked this line to MNPQ by constructing T. The problem was then simply the statement of Brokard's Theorem.

Comment: Evan Chen's Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads is an awesome resource if you want to master the art of solving geometry problems. It is helpful to the master and the novice alike.

Comment: Your solution has been accepted. Thanks for your references and explainations.

Comment: @Blind: I don't mean to seem like I'm always scolding you, and I also mean no disrespect to Anubhab or this nice answer, but ... It's more considerate to wait a while before accepting an answer, especially when you believe a question is "truly hard". Other people may have read the question, and may be taking their time investigating it and writing-up solutions that may (or may not) be simpler and/or more-informative than the first one you receive.

Comment: OK. I will wait one week to accept the solution if there are not another interesting solutions.

Comment: @Blue, agreed. What is the source of the problem, blind?